# How can it be possible to response an invalid email on facebook API?

Tags: facebook, api, email, profile

I requested the facebook api to get a user profile.
Then it responsed following results.

```
{
...
"email": "821026280500",
...
}
```

The email field is just digit characters, an invalid email.

How can it be possible?
Thanks

Comment: Please post your request and the entire result set.

Comment: I guess it's the proxied email..

Answer (score 0):

From their [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), it should not be possible:

> **string** containing a valid RFC822 email address

Perhaps this is an unverified account, which you can check from the verified parameter.

Comment: From their documentation, The **proxied** or contact email address granted by the user